# Cannot perfom Unit test due to context problem?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to perform a basic unit test to save data to in-memory H2 database. Then retrieve and compare it. But I'm stuck on some kind of context problem which i cannot find solution in google.

This is my structure:

[image]

This is my Test:
[image]

And finally my application.properties for the test package:

[image]

When i try to run the test, this is what i get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V

    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:379)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nbu.sportapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>nbu-sport-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>nbu-sport-app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-email-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: When posting code or errors (i.e. stack traces), please post textual snippets using the code formatting options in the editor rather than images.

Comment: Can you show us your dependencies versions (pom)?

Comment: @Matt yes i added it

Comment: You're using `spring-boot-starter-test` v.2.0.4.RELEASE but v. 1.5.7.RELEASE of spring boot. Try to use same versions

Comment: remove version tag from spring-boot-starter-test dep and check again please/

Comment: @Matt I tried 1.5.7.RELEASE version on both but still same problem.

Comment: @MohammadRezaAlagheband nothing changes :(

Comment: i'm also suspicion about your junit dep . can you remove that dependency and try again ? it seems you're mixing junit 4 and 5

Comment: @MohammadRezaAlagheband Trying all kind of combinations but nothing. This is what i get before the error: http://prntscr.com/m43rrt

Comment: You are mixing jars of different versions of the framework. Spring Boot 1.5.7 and 2.0.4. Which leads to mixing Spring 4.3 and 5.0 and you also add 5.1 into the mix. Not to mention the Spring Security stuff. So basically your dependencies are a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dependencies are a mess. You are mixing Spring Boot 1.5.7 with Spring Boot 2.0.4. Which leads to mixing Spring 4.3 and 5.0, next to that you add a Spring Test dependency for Spring 5.1.1 adding yet another version into the mix. Not to mention the Spring Security versions.

So in short your dependencies are a mess. Don't include the `junit` and `spring-test` dependency instead use `spring-boot-starter-test`. The same applies for security use `spring-boot-starter-security` instead.

For the starters don't use a `version` attribute all of those are managed through your `parent` declaration for the `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Apparently you aren't using JUnit5 (yet) so you might want to remove those dependencies as well.

Finally Spring Boot will manage the H2 and MySQL version for you if you want to override those do that in the `properties` section by declaring the a `h2.version` and/or `mysql.version` property. All in all you can remove the `version` tag for those dependencies as well.

Your `dependencies` section should look something like this.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>           
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>            
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-email-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Everything looks way more clean and understandable. I started learning Spring Boot quite recently. Thanks again and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely mixing `spring-core` and `spring-test` dependency versions which leads to `NoSuchMethodError`. Review your project setup and ensure that all Spring dependencies are in the same version.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to figure it out !